# What type of response is returned from the iOS provisioning profile after pressing install

Tags: ios, node.js, provisioning-profile, udid

When you press "install" on an apple device during the provisioning profile set up (from a mobileconfig), what is returned? Is it XML, post values, etc?

I'm trying to extract the device UDID etc via node js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is the POST request

Inside request you get PList with requested parameters. You can find information about PList format here: https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html

And response will look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ICCID</key>
    <string>8901 4104 2541 8901 7521</string>
    <key>IMEI</key>
    <string>01 266900 647352 2</string>
    <key>PRODUCT</key>
    <string>iPad2,2</string>
    <key>UDID</key>
    <string>591f30d41d0bd28597ad962491f1570ddbde4a8a</string>
    <key>VERSION</key>
    <string>8J2</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve this information using Node JS express?

Comment: I believe you can use this package plist.js. You can find usage and code examples on this page: https://www.npmjs.org/package/plist